# gitlab CI/CD how to execute a multiline command as shown

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to execute a command like below in the gitlabl CI/CD

```
ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST <<'ENDSSH'                                                                    
set -x -o verbose;
execute some command here
set +x
ENDSSH
```

How to add such commands in script

```
deploy-to-stage:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - "which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )"
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  script:
    -   *** HERE I WANT TO RUN THAT COMMAND ***
```

How can i do that

Comment: Try creating a shell script file with multi-line command you wanna run. Invoke that as a single command?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 8):

you can do it like that:

```
script:
  - |
    ssh $DEPLOY_USER@$DEPLOY_HOST <<'ENDSSH'                                                                    
    set -x -o verbose;
    execute some command here
    set +x
    ENDSSH
```

Answer (score 0):

`END_TEXT` works as well. As documented by Gitlab

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands

```yaml
  script:
    - |
      ssh user@server.com << END_TEXT
      echo "connected to `hostname` as $USER";
      cd ~/project_folder &&
      git fetch &&
      git log -1 --oneline &&
      git reset --hard origin/master &&
      pnpm install --frozen-lockfile &&
      pnpm run build &&
      sudo service nginx reload
```