# This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs stage config should implement a script: or a trigger: keyword

Tags: ssh, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, cicd

**i have been facing the above error for the below yaml file**

before running the pipeline and getting this error

---

```
stage: deploy
stages: 
  - deploy
Deploy: ~
before_script: 
  - "command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apk add --update openssh )"
  - "eval $(ssh-agent -s)"
  - "echo \"$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY\" | tr -d '\\r' | ssh-add -"
  - "mkdir -p ~/.ssh"
  - "chmod 700 ~/.ssh"
  - "ssh-keyscan $EC2_IPADDRESS >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
  - "chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts"
script: 
  - "mkdir .public"
  - "cp -r * .public"
  - "mv .public public"
  - "zip -r public.zip public"
  - "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no public.zip ubuntu@3.129.128.56:/var/www/html"
  - "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@3.129.128.56 \"cd /var/www/html; touch foo.txt; unzip public.zip\""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69734940/6309) or this [GitLab thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2418) examples of SSH-based pipelines.

In each case, there is no `Deploy: ~`, so try first without this line.

Comment: tried its not working

Comment: @girishgowdadk OK, start simplifying your pipeline, removing lines until it passes (even if that does not do what you need). You will get that way to the line which causes trouble.